# Type last executed message in linux terminal shortcut

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

so I'm looking for a shortcut to automatically fill out the current line with the last executed command, for example, say I executed the `ls` command, now my terminal would look a little something like this:

```
$ >> ls
example.txt important_stuff etc.
$ >>
```

now I want to type ls again without typing it out manually (useful for long lines of command) so my terminal would look like this:

```
$ >> ls
example.txt importand_stuff etc.
$ >> ls
```

what is the shortcut to do this?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Use the history substitution command: `!!`

Comment: I've seen other terminal-based questions here at stack overflow and not only that but there is a tag for it (Terminal and Linux) too so I feel that I've come to the right place, thanks for the suggestion though. @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually press <kbd>↑</kbd> (up arrow) key to bring back the last command. You can press this key multiple times to go through your shell history.

The `history` command will show you recently executed commands, might be useful too.

Comment: hey the Linux I was using didn't support this feature oddly enough (which was why I was asking) but since I've switched Linux types to Kali and am now able to do this thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

Press CTRL+P to switch to the last command, and then press CTRL+O to execute it

Comment: Thanks this worked too not only on my new but my old machine :D Another solution (which was suggested below) would be to use the arrow keys which were a lot simpler but this works to and the only one that worked for the machine was using at the time.